# How to use Lsv2 nvme storage for docker layers in AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm using AKS for hosting gitlab kubernetes runners. And I want to use NVMe storage for docker-related FS (by default it's mounted to as a `/` to system disk with poor IOPS performance) for getting a better build performance.

[Lsv2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/lsv2-series) machines have high-performance NVMe storage on `/dev/nvme0n1`, that is not mounted by default. I can't find and doc, about the configuration of AKS nodes. As I understand my issue can be resolved using mount of `/run/containerd` (or `/var/run/containerd` ?) to the `/dev/nvme0n1` before the `containerd` start.

How can I configure AKS nodes pool to use NVMe for docker cache, R/W fs, fs layers of docker, buildkit cache ?

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?

Comment: No, I have no solution

Comment: Commenting here so that when I find the answer I come back and add it here. It should not be this hard